# Java application which returns a prompt immediately

Tags: java, prompt

Suppose I have a class which has a main method like below and that  `hoge.hoge()`
takes long time to complete.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
 hoge.hoge();
}
```

This application will be executed from the command line. I would like the application to immediately become a background task, exactly as if someone had executed:

```
java AboveClass &
```

I.e. the user should be returned back to the prompt. Is there a way I can achieve this in Java?

Comment: Can you please elaborate the issue .

Comment: Is this question relevant to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551514/create-threads-in-java-to-run-in-background

Comment: It's probably best if you supply a script for your users to run, which starts the Java program and backgrounds it.

Comment: You are mixing up two different topics. Using the "&" character is a Unix feature; it simply puts the started job into the background.

This has nothing to do with the fact that Java allows you to create its own threads.

Comment: @kensuke1984 I have re-written your question to be easier to understand. If I've got anything wrong, please [edit] the question and correct it.

Comment: Thank you @Duncan nothing wrong at all.

Comment: @gilleain yes but if i do this, the prompt does not come back until the thread ends. Thank you!

Comment: @EddyG yeah maybe I should understand the fact java runs on OS more carefully.. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, there is no such way to make the task into a background task. You could try creating a thread (and make it a daemon thread), but I think you'll find that even then if you return from the main method and the thread is still running, the program does not return to the prompt.

@Duncan suggested supplying a script that your users can run, which starts the Java program in the background. I recommend that approach.

If you want an all-Java solution, you could try creating the script in Java. See [How to execute system commands (linux/bsd) using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792024/how-to-execute-system-commands-linux-bsd-using-java) for how to execute commands from a Java program. So, you would execute "java ClassName &" from the Java program then. Not the prettiest solution, but it works. Of course it requires that the "java" command is in the path.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. I will try to create such a script.