# how to continue uploading data including images to rest api like facebook posting

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I am working in building a real estate application
using spring boot java and the application in the aws server and images uploading in s3 bucket

**what i want** is that when the user add a propery if the the user close the app
the uploading task continue in the background and notify when complete

Comment: I would assume that even if you spawn another Thread; if your (Main app Thread) shutsdown, then other threads do as well.

How to spawn a thread.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551514/create-threads-in-java-to-run-in-background

Answer (score 0):

I found a `resumeUpload` method looks like just you want [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html#resumeUpload-com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.PersistableUpload-).

Also an `upload` example in the aws s3 [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/zh_cn/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpu-upload-object.html#multipart-upload-high-level).

Wish this help.