# Is there any way to use multithreading in only one function?

Tags: java, multithreading

Hello I want to use multithreading to save and load a map, I already have a function who save the map and another one who load the map but when these function are called the game freeze. So is there any way to use multithreading only for these function to save the map and play at the same time?

Comment: You might want to include some code to enable us to dig into the issue better. Pls refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You can create a new `Thread` and `start` it, see in example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865315/threads-in-java