# How to stop execution of a method but continue the parent loop?

Tags: java

If the code faced a specific case I want to stop the current execution but continue the parent loop.

```
main() {
     while(line not empty) {
         // blablabla
         method1()
         // tadatadatada
    }
}

method1() {
    // blablabla
    method2()
   // etcetcetc
}

method2() {
    // blablabla
    if (var == 1)
        stop the execution of the current method and parent method
    // etcetcetc
}
```

In the case explained below, if `var == 1`, all `etcetcetc` part of code must not be executed, but `tadatadatada` must be...

So I want to stop all children executions.

Is there a solution to do that in Java?

Comment: You can just `return;` from a method... But I think your example is not sufficient to give that as an answer... Show us the real implementation, please.

Comment: thank you for your answer. However, if I use `return;` in `method2`, code `etcetcetc` will be executed in `method1`...

Comment: You know, that's why I was asking for the real code... I can't tell you from what you have posted so far. Maybe it is not possible to just `return;` in this use case, but nobody will know that without the code.

Comment: you can make method2 return false if you want to quit and then in method1 put the return of method2 in a variable e.g. result=method2(); then check outside if (result==false) break;

Answer (score 0):

Return a value from `method2` and check it in `method1`. If it meets a condition, `return` from `method1` too.

Something like:

```
method1() {
  var shouldBreak = method2();
  if (shouldBreak) {
    return 
  }
  // more stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into Java **Multithreading**. This will allow you to run multiple methods simultaneously and give you full control over when to stop a specific thread.

Here's a starting point from another: [Threads in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865315/threads-in-java)

I don't quite understand fully what you're asking as your example doesn't have extensive clarity, but hopefully this is what you're looking for.