# Is there a way to start a program N times at once?

Tags: python, selenium

I am making a python bot that makes twitter accounts, just for educational purposes with throw-away emails (catchalls) and russian phonenumbers. I managed to get through both email and phone verification and was wondering if I can create accounts at a large scale by starting N webdrivers at once.

Right now I made a code that only loops the program N times. I removed the code but it looked like this:

```
amount = input....
for i in range(amount)
       App.run()
```

This was my only hope in actually doing this. Does anyone know how I can do this and if a computer can actually handle 10 or 100 headless webdrivers from selenium at once?

Comment: Running chrome-driver with any concurrency in the same environment could be problematic.

Comment: Precisely, while attempting to initiate _10 or 100 headless webdrivers_ you may soon run into [CPU and memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50701824/limit-chrome-headless-cpu-and-memory-usage/52680811#52680811) issues.

Comment: Sometimes I see services that sell like 10k followers... How do they fix these kind of problems?

Comment: for Selenium using HTMLUnit might be your best bet... less resources.  You may be better off just generating the proper calls directly to Twitter using Curl or Postman or any language:  https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/create-manage-lists/api-reference/post-lists-create

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to create multiple threads instead of looping, then you can start each upload in parallel threads. You are on the right track. You don't need a selenium grid to achieve this.

lookup about multithreading. You can start with this answer([Threads in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865315/threads-in-java))

It's not right you need grid for executing multiple browser sessions. You can invoke multiple browser sessions by just creating multiple driver objects, and managing them. Each session will be separate if you want them to be.

Grid is for scaling as there is a limitation on the no of browser instances you can run keeping your machine performance intact and tests stable. Like more than 5 chrome instances in a single machine. If you want to do more than that then you have to use selenium Grid.